# Laravel Blade templating conditional formatting

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm new to Laravel/MVC in general, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm migrating a legacy procedural app and am trying to echo separate database rows (fetched through an Eloquent model) for "Title, City, State, Country" as comma separated values.

The Blade template I have now currently looks like this, which is functional but hideous.

```
@foreach ($projects as $projects) 
{{ $projects->title}}{{ $projects->city? ', '.$projects->city : ""}}{{ $projects->state?  ', '.$projects->state : "" }}{{ $projects->country? ', '.$projects->country : "" }}
@endforeach
```

Is there a better way to do this? the legacy procedural code pushes it to an array and implodes it like below, but if I did do an array push/implode I'm not too sure whether it belongs in the Eloquent model or controller.

```
$tempArray = array();
if($row["city"]) array_push($tempArray, convert_text($row["city"]));
if($row["state"]) array_push($tempArray, convert_text($row["state"]));
if($row["country"]) array_push($tempArray, convert_text($row["country"]));
echo implode(", ", $tempArray);
echo (count($tempArray) > 0)?", ":"";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. this should work:

```
@foreach ($projects as $project) 
    {{ implode(', ', array_filter([$project->city, $project->state, $project->country])) }}
@endforeach
```

**Update:**
`$project->attributes` is protected, so I adjusted the code above to `$project->getAttributes()`.

**Update 2:** I missed the point of excluding the attributes that have an empty string, so I added `array_filter()` to the code above to filter out the ones that have a "falsy" value (such as an empty string, or `null`).

**Update 3:** Realized that you want the attributes in a specific order.. and also realized that the code could be a lot simpler, so removed the `array_only()` and `$project->getAttributes()`.

Comment: Was just about to comment on the empty string issue but I saw that you updated. Thank you so much, worked like a charm and was infinitely more elegant than all the solutions I had come up with. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Note that I just made another update, this also gives you the attributes in the order that you want, and the code is simpler.